# как реализовать запросы к базе данных в php который реагирует на время?

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно реализовать раздел на сайте, который будет отвечать за резервацию футбольного поля на один час.

Хочу сделать так чтобы был список доступного времени (например, 12-00,13-00,14-00...) Когда посетитель выбирает определенное время, оно должно удаляться из списка, и возвращаться только после того как это время истечёт...
Например, я выбрал 13-00 (теперь мой список 12-00, 14-00), т.е. 13-00 удаленно из списка и оно должно появиться только когда наступит 14-00.

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом, не знаю как реализовать чтобы база реагировала на время.

---

связанные вопросы:

- [Как удалить информацию из базы через заданный промежуток времени?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/480092/178576)
- [Реализация удаления из базы данных через промежуток времени без использования cron](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486348/178576)

Comment: Вам надо делать иначе: создаете в php часовой массив. А в базе данных храните "занятые" часы. При отображении информации пролистываете сквозь массив и проверяете каждый час. Если запись есть - не показываете ничего. Записи нет - показываете с кнопкой "зарезервировать"

Comment: Спасибо,буду пытаться разобраться,....А за что мне опять -1 поставили,я же вроде правильно оформил вопрос?

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень похож на "сделайте за меня". Скорее всего минусовавшие так и решили. Оформили Вы все верно за одним исключением: если бы Вы написали как думаете решать проблему, свои варианты, то было бы лучше... Тогда ясно, что Вы хотя бы думали над решением...

Comment: Зачем только вы еще один вопрос задали, да еще и в такой непонятной форме.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Зачем 3 одинаковых вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать cron.
Пользователь выбирает время, например 13:00, это время записываете в БД, на странице показываете только то время, которое не занято. Далее скрипт по расписанию проверяет БД и возвращает занятое время, т.е. в 14:00 скрипт запускается и проверяет было ли занято время на 13:00, если да, то делает это время доступным, если нет останавливаем скрипт.

Answer (score 1):

Сформулирую в общих словах идею:

В базу записывайте резервируемый час (причем час обязательно должен быть увязан с датой). Когда отображаете список достуного для резервирования времени - берите список и убираете время, которое в резерве. Таким образом можно будет организовать резервирование на любой промежуток времени (не только на ближайшие сутки).

При необходимости удаляйте раз в сутки старые резервы.