# Как удалить информацию из базы через заданный промежуток времени?

Tags: php, mysql

Как установить время удаления информации из базы данных в php? Хочу сделать так чтобы был список доступного времени, например 12-00, 13-00, 14-00... Когда посетитель выбирает определённое время, оно должно удаляться из списка, и появляться там только после того как это время истечёт... Например, я выбрал 13-00 (теперь мой список 12-00, 14-00) , т.е. 13-00 удаленно из базы и оно должно появиться, только когда наступит 14-00

---

связанные вопросы:

- [как реализовать запросы к базе данных в php который реагирует на время?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/480067/178576)
- [Реализация удаления из базы данных через промежуток времени без использования cron](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486348/178576)

Comment: А другой способ есть,просто я с cron совсем не знаком?

Comment: Хочу сделать так чтобы был список доступного времени,на пример 12-00,13-00,14-00.....Когда посетитель выбирает определйнное время,оно должно удаляться из списка, и появляться там только после того как это время истечёт...Например, я выбрал 13-00 (теперь мой список 12-00,14-00) , т.е. 13-00 удаленно из базы и оно должно появиться,только когда наступит 14-00.

Comment: если судить по вашему комментарию, все наоборот: *..Когда посетитель выбирает определйнное время,оно должно удаляться* те. удаляем при выборе. А когда выводим форму со списком времен, добавляем *только после того как это время истечёт*. никаких отложенных действий

Comment: Поясните еще раз другими словами что вы хотите получить? При чем тут вообще база? Удаление (может быть просто скрытие для текущего пользователя?) должно происходить только до наступления указанного времени в ближайших сутках?

Comment: А почему именно `php`? Почему нельзя воспользоваться `MySQL` `CREATE EVENT`?

Comment: @cyadvert Разве кто-то говорил, что нельзя?

Comment: @tutankhamun, логично.... Ух, как я ща запостю ответ!

Comment: @cyadvert Пишите, конечно. А я вот вообще не уверен что вопрос про БД :\

Comment: Перечитал вопрос - да уж, занесло меня.... :( Предложение о `CREATE EVENT` снимается...

Comment: Я спутал с другим обсуждением этой же темы от этого же автора: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480067/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-php-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F

Comment: @pavel Ну cron в принципе не обязательно. Если вы вставляете в базу запись 13:00 что бы пользователь видел все, кроме 13:00 то вы и ориентируетесь на эту запись. В эту же запись в базе вы кладете абсолютное время, после которого запись должна удалится. Только вы решите, когда именно удалять запись, если сейчас 14:35, а пользователь отмечает 13:00. После того как абсолютное время определено, вы можете при обращении любого пользователя делать `delete from table where dt<now()`. Только вообще сам подход с удалением записей по времени странный, мне кажется вам нужно что то совсем другое

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Не нужно ничего удалять – только создавать! : )

По умолчанию доступно всё (рабочее) время. Когда юзер что-то выбирает – его выбор сохраняется навсегда в базе.

При очередном визите из БД выбираются все забронированные моменты в будущем, и показываются всё время минус занятые моменты.

Напр., доступны три слота: 12,13,14 - об этом «знает» ваш php скрипт, в нём это жёстко прописано, или же он считывает доступное расписание из БД.

Зашла Аня, и заняла себе время 14 – в БД в таблице «Бронь» сохранилась запись `Аня, 2016-01-05 14:00:00`.

Зашёл Боря в 13:15. Из базы считалось, что на сегодня 14 уже занято – ему показывают 12 и 13, если логика вашего приложения допускает предлагать сеансы в прошедшем времени и уже начавшиеся.

Зашёл Боря на следующий день в 9 утра. Из базы считалось, что на тот день ещё ничего не занято, ему показывают 12,13,14.

Ну и можно раз в сутки в полночь запускать по крону скрипт, который просто очистит всю таблицу с занятыми слотами.

Comment: С вопроса пока не совсем понятно удаляется ли выбранное время только для юзера который выбрал его или для всех других юзеров тоже. В общем исходной информации все равно недостаточно

Comment: @stckvrw из [другого вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480067/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-php-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) того же юзера я узнал, что задача – бронирование времени на футбольном поле – бронирует один, видно всем.