# Реализация удаления из базы данных через промежуток времени без использования cron

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно реализовать систему удаления/изменения в базе данных без использования cron?

Я предполагаю, что это можно сделать с помощью функций mysql для дат.

У меня должен быть раздел на сайте, где пользователь будет бронировать (баскетбольное поле), в списке представлено время (9-00, 10-00, 11-00 ...).

Когда он забранировал 10-00, это время уходит из списка. Как его вернуть обратно, если время уже 11-00 часов и баскетбольное поле им уже не используется?

---

связанные вопросы:

- [как реализовать запросы к базе данных в php который реагирует на время?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/480067/178576)
- [Как удалить информацию из базы через заданный промежуток времени?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/480092/178576)

Comment: А зачем его возвращать обратно, если время уже прошло?

Comment: @pavel А вы время храните вместе с датой и не надо будет его освобождать, заодно появится возможность забронировать 10:00 следующей пятницы. А не только на сегодня

Comment: ну было бы неплохо структуру таблиц увидеть. На вскидку - добавляете поле `reservation_to`, в котором храните дату и время брони, а при выборке проверяете доступность брони: `select (reservation_to < UTC_TIMESTAMP()) AS reservation_available`. Т.е. сделали выборку, а потом проверяете доступность брони (ну или сразу в выборке это делаете) Только неплохо было бы не замещать бронь, а предоставить возможность бронировать на несколько дней вперед, а значит нужна еще одна таблица брони

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, чтобы потом можно было еще забронировать? Как билеты на автобус, например

Comment: @BOPOH ну так время этого дня уже прошло, значит можно заказать только на следующий. А оно не должно быть связано с сегодняшним 10:00

Comment: Нужно сделать чтобы бронь была только на одни сутки

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну так автор и хочет узнать как это сделать

Comment: @pavel вы в пользовательском интерфейсе можете сделать бронь только на сегодня, но в базу писать вместе с датой и из базы выбирать только записи с бронью больше текущей даты_времени. Хотя бы потому, что после того как это заработает вас через неделю попросят показать какую нибудь статистику по броням за последний месяц скажем. А без cron или event в самой СУБД вы это не решите никак, потому что за день на сайт может вообще никто не зайти и зайдут в 9 утра следующего дня ...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить информацию из базы через заданный промежуток времени?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480092/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8)

Comment: без крона можно только по запросу.

Answer (score 3):

более логично будет сохранять не только время, но и дату.

в этом случае не понадобится ничего удалять/изменять в какие-то заданные моменты времени.

просто, если событие в будущем (чтобы оно не выходило за пределы одних суток — должна следить программа, хотя, конечно, при необходимости можно сделать ограничение и средствами *mysql*), то это время *занято*. а если уже в прошлом — то *свободно*.

вот пример организации таблицы и запросов для получения свободного/занятого времени:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df8ce9/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (v datetime);

insert into t values
   ("2016/01/20 10:00")
  ,("2016/01/21 10:00")
  ,("2016/01/22 12:00")
  ,("2016/01/27 12:00")
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select distinct date_format(v,"%H:%i") as zanjato
from t  
where v >= now()
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df8ce9/3/0)**:

```
| zanjato |
|---------|
|   12:00 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select distinct date_format(ts.v,"%H:%i") as svobodno
from t as ts
where ts.v < now() and time(ts.v) not in (
  select time(tz.v)
  from t as tz
  where tz.v >= now()
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df8ce9/3/1)**:

```
| svobodno |
|----------|
|    10:00 |
```